# How to draw a line under words in JTextPane?

Tags: java, swing

I am making a dictionary, and I am trying to draw a curved line under the word if the word isn't found in the database (if is a wrong word).

How should this be done?

Answer (score 2):

You could create a custom Highlighter. See [Rectangle Painter](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/10/28/rectangle-painter/) for an example to get you started.

The following code might help with the drawing of the squiggles:

```
    for (int i = x1; i <= x2; i += 6) {
        g.drawArc(i + 3, y - 3, 3, 3, 0, 180);
        g.drawArc(i + 6, y - 3, 3, 3, 180, 181);
    }
```

x1/x2 would be the start/end x position.

Edit:

I created a `SquigglePainter` class that can be found at the `Rectangle Painter` link.